# Tracking Current Section and Putting in a String Format

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good Afternoon,

I am struggling to do the last bit on my website, i am nearly there but i am pulling my hair out, i have been staring at this for days and can't figure out where i am going wrong.

I am using an up and down buttons to call a JQuery Script which loads next section or previous section.

This is the JQuery code.

```
    <script>

function getCurrentSection () {
    var cutoff = $(window).scrollTop();
    var curIndex = 0;
    for(var index = 0; index < $('section').length; index++){
        if ($('section').eq(index).offset().top >= cutoff) {
            curIndex = index;
            break;
        }
    }
    return curIndex;
};

$( document ).ready(function() {

      var curIndex = getCurrentSection();
      curIndex += curIndex +1;
      var maxSec = $('section').length;

    document.getElementById("sectionText").innerHTML = curIndex.toString() + " / " + maxSec.toString();

});

$('#scrollWindowUp').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var curIndex = getCurrentSection();
    var maxSec = $('section').length;

        document.getElementById("sectionText").innerHTML = curIndex.toString() + " / " + maxSec.toString();

    if (curIndex === 0) { return; }
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($('section').eq(curIndex-1).offset().top - 1)},500);


});

$('#scrollWindowDown').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var curIndex = getCurrentSection();
    var maxSec = $('section').length;

     document.getElementById("sectionText").innerHTML = curIndex.toString() + " / " + maxSec.toString();

    if (curIndex === $('section').length) { return; }
    var cutoff = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ($('section').eq(curIndex).offset().top !== cutoff+1) { curIndex = curIndex-1; } /* Check if the current section is at the top of the page or has been scrolled */

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($('section').eq(curIndex+1).offset().top - 1)},500);

});

</script>
```

It is called by my List and here is the code that calls the JQuery.

```
    <ul class="list-group fixed-pagination">
      <li class="list-group-item pagButton"><a href="#" id="scrollWindowUp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>

  <li class="list-group-item pagButton"><p id="sectionText"></p></li>

  <li class="list-group-item pagButton"><a href="#" id="scrollWindowDown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

This list is fixed to the side of the screen and in the span i want it to detect the max amount of sections of the page, and then say what the current section the user is on.

It is nearly there and getting the max sections but when i click up and down it goes crazy with the current section number, and when the page initially loads i also want it to say the current section which will be 1.

Hope you can help me and see where i am going wrong, my current page is http://diosa.smudgehost.co.uk and you can see what i have achieved and what is happening on the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it myself, i fixed it by modifying the code to this, in case anybody ever wants to use it.

```
var CurSect = getCurrentSection();
var CurNum = CurSect+1;
var MaxSect = $('section').length;

$( document ).ready(function() {

document.getElementById("sectionText").innerHTML = CurNum.toString() + " / " + MaxSect.toString();
});

function getCurrentSection () {
    var cutoff = $(window).scrollTop();
    var curIndex = 0;
    for(var index = 0; index < $('section').length; index++){
        if ($('section').eq(index).offset().top >= cutoff) {
            curIndex = index;

            break;
        }
    }
    return curIndex;

};


$('#scrollWindowUp').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var curIndex = getCurrentSection();

    if (curIndex === 0) { return; }

    document.getElementById("sectionText").innerHTML = curIndex.toString() + " / " + MaxSect.toString();

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($('section').eq(curIndex-1).offset().top - 1)},500);

});

$('#scrollWindowDown').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var curIndex = getCurrentSection();

    if (curIndex === $('section').length) { return;  }


    var cutoff = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ($('section').eq(curIndex).offset().top !== cutoff+1)
    { 
        curIndex = curIndex-1; 
    } /* Check if the current section is at the top of the page or has been scrolled */

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($('section').eq(curIndex+1).offset().top - 1)},500);

    curIndex+=2;

    document.getElementById("sectionText").innerHTML = curIndex.toString() + " / " + MaxSect.toString();

});
```